# How does one remove Webpack code from the build?

Tags: webpack

I have some simple code like the this:

```js
// src/common.js
let add = (a,b) => a+b
console.log(add(2,6))
```

But after Webpack processes it, some code is added to the output and the file size is increased to about 6.5kb:

```js
// dist/common.js
!function(t){var e={};function n(r){if(e[r])return e[r].exports;var o=e[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return t[r].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,n),o.l=!0,o.exports}n.m=t,n.c=e,n.d=function(t,e,r){n.o(t,e)||Object.defineProperty(t,e,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},n.r=function(t){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(t,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",{value:!0})},n.t=function(t,e){if(1&e&&(t=n(t)),8&e)return t;if(4&e&&"object"==typeof t&&t&&t.__esModule)return t;var r=Object.create(null);if(n.r(r),Object.defineProperty(r,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:t}),2&e&&"string"!=typeof t)for(var o in t)n.d(r,o,function(e){return t[e]}.bind(null,o));return r},n.n=function(t){var e=t&&t.__esModule?function(){return t.default}:function(){return t};return n.d(e,"a",e),e},n.o=function(t,e){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t,e)},n.p="/",n(n.s=0)}([function(t,e,n){"use strict";n.r(e);n(1),n(2)},function(t,e){console.log(2+6)},function(t,e,n){var r=n(3);"string"==typeof r&&(r=[[t.i,r,""]]);var o={hmr:!0,transform:void 0,insertInto:void 0};n(4)(r,o);r.locals&&(t.exports=r.locals)},function(t,e,n){},function(t,e,n){var r,o,i={},s=(r=function(){return window&&document&&document.all&&!window.atob},function(){return void 0===o&&(o=r.apply(this,arguments)),o}),a=function(t){var e={};return function(t,n){if("function"==typeof t)return t();if(void 0===e[t]){var r=function(t,e){return e?e.querySelector(t):document.querySelector(t)}.call(this,t,n);if(window.HTMLIFrameElement&&r instanceof window.HTMLIFrameElement)try{r=r.contentDocument.head}catch(t){r=null}e[t]=r}return e[t]}}(),f=null,u=0,c=[],l=n(5);function p(t,e){for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){var r=t[n],o=i[r.id];if(o){o.refs++;for(var s=0;s<o.parts.length;s++)o.parts[s](r.parts[s]);for(;s<r.parts.length;s++)o.parts.push(m(r.parts[s],e))}else{var a=[];for(s=0;s<r.parts.length;s++)a.push(m(r.parts[s],e));i[r.id]={id:r.id,refs:1,parts:a}}}}function d(t,e){for(var n=[],r={},o=0;o<t.length;o++){var i=t[o],s=e.base?i[0]+e.base:i[0],a={css:i[1],media:i[2],sourceMap:i[3]};r[s]?r[s].parts.push(a):n.push(r[s]={id:s,parts:[a]})}return n}function v(t,e){var n=a(t.insertInto);if(!n)throw new Error("Couldn't find a style target. This probably means that the value for the 'insertInto' parameter is invalid.");var r=c[c.length-1];if("top"===t.insertAt)r?r.nextSibling?n.insertBefore(e,r.nextSibling):n.appendChild(e):n.insertBefore(e,n.firstChild),c.push(e);else if("bottom"===t.insertAt)n.appendChild(e);else{if("object"!=typeof t.insertAt||!t.insertAt.before)throw new Error("[Style Loader]\n\n Invalid value for parameter 'insertAt' ('options.insertAt') found.\n Must be 'top', 'bottom', or Object.\n (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader#insertat)\n");var o=a(t.insertAt.before,n);n.insertBefore(e,o)}}function h(t){if(null===t.parentNode)return!1;t.parentNode.removeChild(t);var e=c.indexOf(t);e>=0&&c.splice(e,1)}function b(t){var e=document.createElement("style");if(void 0===t.attrs.type&&(t.attrs.type="text/css"),void 0===t.attrs.nonce){var r=function(){0;return n.nc}();r&&(t.attrs.nonce=r)}return y(e,t.attrs),v(t,e),e}function y(t,e){Object.keys(e).forEach(function(n){t.setAttribute(n,e[n])})}function m(t,e){var n,r,o,i;if(e.transform&&t.css){if(!(i="function"==typeof e.transform?e.transform(t.css):e.transform.default(t.css)))return function(){};t.css=i}if(e.singleton){var s=u++;n=f||(f=b(e)),r=x.bind(null,n,s,!1),o=x.bind(null,n,s,!0)}else t.sourceMap&&"function"==typeof URL&&"function"==typeof URL.createObjectURL&&"function"==typeof URL.revokeObjectURL&&"function"==typeof Blob&&"function"==typeof btoa?(n=function(t){var e=document.createElement("link");return void 0===t.attrs.type&&(t.attrs.type="text/css"),t.attrs.rel="stylesheet",y(e,t.attrs),v(t,e),e}(e),r=function(t,e,n){var r=n.css,o=n.sourceMap,i=void 0===e.convertToAbsoluteUrls&&o;(e.convertToAbsoluteUrls||i)&&(r=l(r));o&&(r+="\n/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,"+btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(o))))+" */");var s=new Blob([r],{type:"text/css"}),a=t.href;t.href=URL.createObjectURL(s),a&&URL.revokeObjectURL(a)}.bind(null,n,e),o=function(){h(n),n.href&&URL.revokeObjectURL(n.href)}):(n=b(e),r=function(t,e){var n=e.css,r=e.media;r&&t.setAttribute("media",r);if(t.styleSheet)t.styleSheet.cssText=n;else{for(;t.firstChild;)t.removeChild(t.firstChild);t.appendChild(document.createTextNode(n))}}.bind(null,n),o=function(){h(n)});return r(t),function(e){if(e){if(e.css===t.css&&e.media===t.media&&e.sourceMap===t.sourceMap)return;r(t=e)}else o()}}t.exports=function(t,e){if("undefined"!=typeof DEBUG&&DEBUG&&"object"!=typeof document)throw new Error("The style-loader cannot be used in a non-browser environment");(e=e||{}).attrs="object"==typeof e.attrs?e.attrs:{},e.singleton||"boolean"==typeof e.singleton||(e.singleton=s()),e.insertInto||(e.insertInto="head"),e.insertAt||(e.insertAt="bottom");var n=d(t,e);return p(n,e),function(t){for(var r=[],o=0;o<n.length;o++){var s=n[o];(a=i[s.id]).refs--,r.push(a)}t&&p(d(t,e),e);for(o=0;o<r.length;o++){var a;if(0===(a=r[o]).refs){for(var f=0;f<a.parts.length;f++)a.parts[f]();delete i[a.id]}}}};var g,w=(g=[],function(t,e){return g[t]=e,g.filter(Boolean).join("\n")});function x(t,e,n,r){var o=n?"":r.css;if(t.styleSheet)t.styleSheet.cssText=w(e,o);else{var i=document.createTextNode(o),s=t.childNodes;s[e]&&t.removeChild(s[e]),s.length?t.insertBefore(i,s[e]):t.appendChild(i)}}},function(t,e){t.exports=function(t){var e="undefined"!=typeof window&&window.location;if(!e)throw new Error("fixUrls requires window.location");if(!t||"string"!=typeof t)return t;var n=e.protocol+"//"+e.host,r=n+e.pathname.replace(/\/[^\/]*$/,"/");return t.replace(/url\s*\(((?:[^)(]|\((?:[^)(]+|\([^)(]*\))*\))*)\)/gi,function(t,e){var o,i=e.trim().replace(/^"(.*)"$/,function(t,e){return e}).replace(/^'(.*)'$/,function(t,e){return e});return/^(#|data:|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|file:\/\/\/|\s*$)/i.test(i)?t:(o=0===i.indexOf("//")?i:0===i.indexOf("/")?n+i:r+i.replace(/^\.\//,""),"url("+JSON.stringify(o)+")")})}}]);
```

Setting optimization.runtimeChunk to true only splits the code into two files: `app.js` and `runtime~app.js`

```js
// Webpack.conf.js
optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    runtimeChunk: true,

    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all'
    }
  }
```

I also tried to create another entry point for my js output but it still adds some code unneeded code but in this case not so much

```js
// Webpack.conf.js
entry: {
    app: PATHS.src,
    common: `${PATHS.src}/js/common.js`
}
```

```js
// dist/common.js
!function(e){var t={};function n(r){if(t[r])return t[r].exports;var o=t[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,n),o.l=!0,o.exports}n.m=e,n.c=t,n.d=function(e,t,r){n.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},n.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},n.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=n(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var r=Object.create(null);if(n.r(r),Object.defineProperty(r,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var o in e)n.d(r,o,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,o));return r},n.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return n.d(t,"a",t),t},n.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},n.p="/",n(n.s=5)}({5:function(e,t){console.log(2+6)}});
```

If I try to both add new chunk and set optimization.runtimeChunk to true, I get the following:

```js
// dist/common.js
(window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[]).push([[1],{5:function(o,n){console.log(2+6)}},[[5,3]]]);

// dist/runtime~common.js
!function(e){function r(r){for(var n,f,i=r[0],l=r[1],a=r[2],c=0,s=[];c<i.length;c++)f=i[c],o[f]&&s.push(o[f][0]),o[f]=0;for(n in l)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(l,n)&&(e[n]=l[n]);for(p&&p(r);s.length;)s.shift()();return u.push.apply(u,a||[]),t()}function t(){for(var e,r=0;r<u.length;r++){for(var t=u[r],n=!0,i=1;i<t.length;i++){var l=t[i];0!==o[l]&&(n=!1)}n&&(u.splice(r--,1),e=f(f.s=t[0]))}return e}var n={},o={3:0},u=[];function f(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var t=n[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,f),t.l=!0,t.exports}f.m=e,f.c=n,f.d=function(e,r,t){f.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},f.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},f.t=function(e,r){if(1&r&&(e=f(e)),8&r)return e;if(4&r&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var t=Object.create(null);if(f.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&r&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var n in e)f.d(t,n,function(r){return e[r]}.bind(null,n));return t},f.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return f.d(r,"a",r),r},f.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},f.p="/";var i=window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[],l=i.push.bind(i);i.push=r,i=i.slice();for(var a=0;a<i.length;a++)r(i[a]);var p=l;t()}([]);
```

So here are a few questions:

1. What does that code do?
2. Why is it generated?
3. How does one get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code implements the module system, for `require()` / `import`.

If you aren't using those, there is probably no point in using Webpack.

If you are, you need that code.

Comment: Well I use Webpack to optimize my bundle and assets, preprocess scss and use babel. But I still don't get what that code does...

Comment: If you use rollup bundler, code like this won't be generated